# How to take property value from command line, if not from the environment, if not - the default?

Tags: maven, maven-2

I would like to define the default value of a propery in my maven pom file. However, the dev should be able to override it with an environment variable of the same name, which in turn should be overridden if the same property is specified on the command line to mvn.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best you can do is define the default value of a property which can be overriden if the same property is specified on the command line.

**This configuration has been tested under maven 2.2.1.**

1. Define you property in your pom:

   ```
   <properties>
            <finalname>dropbox</finalname>
   </properties>
   ```
2. Use it somewhere in the pom, e.g.

   ```
      <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <archive>
                   <manifest>
                       <mainClass>com.dengjintian.uploader.Main</mainClass>
                   </manifest>
               </archive>
               <descriptorRefs>
                   <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
               </descriptorRefs>
               <finalName>${finalname}</finalName>
               <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
           </configuration>
           <!-- This will bind assembly:make-assembly to the package phase -->
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>make-assembly</id>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>single</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```
3. Overwrite it via command line:

   ```
   mvn clean install  -Dfinalname=dropboxtmp
   ```

Comment: Is it possible to integrate the environment variables somewhere?

Comment: I think it's impossible in maven 2.2.1 after a few tries. Maven reference environment variable, e.g. xxx,  via  ${env.xxx}. You can define it via "export xxx=yyy". But if you put such variable in the <properties> block, it can be *only* overwrite via command line.

Comment: That worked like a charm... I can override the property in a profile from the configuration element.